# Is the php json extension still useful (php >= 5.2)?

Tags: php

From php.net, I found this line :

> As of PHP 5.2.0, the JSON extension is bundled and compiled into PHP by default. http://php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php

So why this php extension still exist ? For example : php7.2-json

Are we talking about the same json extension ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the extension is bundled (i.e. shipped inside the main zip without the need to download it from an external repository), or compiled (i.e. directly available from your PHP code without the need to explicitly activate it in `ini` files), does not mean that the source code of the extension was removed altogether.

The source code of many features in PHP is organised in extensions -- be them external, dynamic, or statically compiled and bundled).
You will still find the php json extension as a standalone lib ; but you should not need to install it on its own, nor activate it in `ini` files.

Comment: Ok, i realize my question is a little bit _hasty_, your arguments are good! :)